# Need help with a LINQ Query using the Dynamic LINQ Library

Tags: vb.net, linq, dynamic-linq

Forgive my ignorance on this.
I have this LINQ Query:
Dim ngBikersDataContext As New CarBikeWalkDataContext

```
bikersList = (From c In ngBikersDataContext.Reg_Bikers _
                        Order By c.L_Name _
                        Select New Bikers() With { _
                        .BikerID = c.BikerID, _
                        .F_Name = c.F_Name, _
                        .M_Name = c.M_Name, _
                        .L_Name = c.L_Name _
                        }).ToList()
```

As you can see it is a LIST(OF ). Here is the definition of the bikersList:

```
Dim bikersList As List(Of Bikers) = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.Session("Bikers"), List(Of Bikers))
```

I need to be able to sort, so was going to use the Dynamic LINQ Library. So I added it to my project Imported System.Linq.Dynamic and tried to use this code:

```
bikersList = (ngBikersDataContext.Reg_Bikers _
                    .OrderBy(SortExpression) _
                    .Select New Bikers() With { _
                        .BikerID = c.BikerID, _
                        .F_Name = c.F_Name, _
                        .M_Name = c.M_Name, _
                        .L_Name = c.L_Name _
                        }).ToList()
```

But now I am getting the blue scwiggly line under:

```
                    ngBikersDataContext.Reg_Bikers _
                    .OrderBy(SortExpression) _
                    .Select
```

with the error "Overload resolution failed because no accesible 'Select' accepts this number of arguments."
Over the "NEW" I get an error " ')'expected."

Would someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up 'extension method' syntax with 'query syntax'.

```
bikersList = (ngBikersDataContext.Reg_Bikers _
                .OrderBy(SortExpression) _
                .Select(Function(c) New Bikers() With { _
                    .BikerID = c.BikerID, _
                    .F_Name = c.F_Name, _
                    .M_Name = c.M_Name, _
                    .L_Name = c.L_Name _
                    })).ToList()
```

Or

```
bikersList = (From c in ngBikersDataContext.Reg_Bikers.OrderBy(SortExpression) _
              Select b = New Bikers() With { _
                    .BikerID = c.BikerID, _
                    .F_Name = c.F_Name, _
                    .M_Name = c.M_Name, _
                    .L_Name = c.L_Name _
                    }).ToList()
```